# Error defining an array

Tags: c, function, binary-search

I want to introduce as stated in the title, a binary search function to my program. But keep getting two errors which I have no clue how resolve.

This is the compiling-error I get for my code:

```
: expected expression before '{' token
 array[size]={1,3,6,8,12,13,16};
             ^
upg10.8.c: In function 'binarySearch':
upg10.8.c:55:7: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-
 type]
       }
       ^
```

Any idea to what is causing the problem in both cases?
You can find the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int binarySearch(int n, int array[], int search);

int main(void){

int search, size=7, array[size], middle;

array[size]={1,3,6,8,12,13,16};



printf("input search number:\n");
scanf("%d", &search);

middle  = binarySearch(size, array, search);

if(middle ==-1){
printf("There is no index corresponding to that search number");
}
else{
printf("Index %d for Search%d", middle, search);
}

  return 0;
}

int binarySearch(int n, int array[], int search){
  int first =0;
  int last = n-1;
  int middle= (first+last)/2;


  while(first<=last){
  if(array[middle]<search)
  first= middle +1;
  else if(array[middle]==search){

    return search;
  }
      else
      last = middle -1;

      middle = (first +last )/2;

      return middle;
      break;
    }

if(array[first]>array[last])
return -1;

      }
```

Comment: If you want to declare an initial value for the array, then you must do so in its declaration.  Elsewhere, you can assign only to individual elements, not to the whole array.  Additionally, suppose control passes out of the `while` loop in your `binarySearch()` function.  If you can be certain that `array[first]>array[last]` in that case, then you should *unconditionally* return `-1`.  Otherwise, you must specify a return value in the case that that condition does not hold.

Comment: `array[size]={1,3,6,8,12,13,16};` makes no sense in C. What were you trying to do by this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `array[size]={1,3,6,8,12,13,16};`. You cant initialize value to array after declaration. But only on the time of deceleration. The correct code is

```
int array[]={1,3,6,8,12,13,16};
```

Also declare size as macro constant. I think its better. It will look like

```
#define size 7
```

Everything else look fine!!

Comment: Thank you. it worked.  However, why am I not able to initlize the values for the array like: 

     
     'int array[size]={1,3,6,8,12,13,16};'

Comment: Because you are trying to assign set of values into a single variable array[size] or array[7].  That is why it shows an error. If this solutions helps please check answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: @oxodo: What do you mean by "not able"? If `size` is a constant, then you *are* able to do it. If `size` is not constant, then you won't be able to do it, since VLA do not accept initializers. What is `size` in your case?

Answer (score 0):

```
int search, size=7, array[size], middle;
```

Here you've defined the array object `array`.  Note that the size is not a constant, so this is a VLA (variable-length array).  Not all compilers support VLAs, and you don't need one here.

```
array[size]={1,3,6,8,12,13,16};
```

This is several kinds of wrong.

`array[size]` would be element 7 of `array` -- but `array` only has elements 0 through 6.

You obviously mean to assign the 7 values `{1,3,6,8,12,13,16}` to the 7 elements of `array`, but you can't do it this way. In fact, array objects can be initialized, but they can't be assigned to (for complicated historical reasons).

`{1,3,6,8,12,13,16}` is not an expression, so it can't appear on the right hand side of an assignment, regardless of what's on the left.  It is a valid initializer.

Drop the definition of `size` and change the declaration of `array` to this:

```
int array[] = {1,3,6,8,12,13,16};
```

Since you've initialized `array` with 7 elements, you don't have to tell the compiler how many elements it has; the size is determined for you automatically. (That's one of the few things C will helpfully do for you.)

Now you could define

```
const int size = 7;
```

but then you'd have to carefully update the initializers for `array` and `size` together, and make sure they're consistent.  Instead, you can compute the size:

```
const int size = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
```